# Как превратить множитель в проценты?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть множитель 1.15, на который умножаются другие числа. Нужно чтобы 1.15 при выводе на экран, отображалось как 15%, а не как 1.15. Дайте формулу, пожалуйста. (да, математику прогуливал, и гугл не помог)

```
public TMP_Text textDisplay;
public double a = 1.15;

public void PrintText() 
{
    textDisplay.text = "You received: " + a + "%";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А подумать не вариант?

```
(x - 1) * 100
```

Comment: Спасибо. Говорю же, математику прогуливал

Comment: `Подумать` и `прогуглить математику` - это немного разные вещи, увы

Comment: @МаксимФисман я не писал ПРОГУГЛИТЬ математику. Я написал ПРОГУЛИВАЛ, следовательно, размышлять о том, чего не знаешь - сложно. Читайте внимательно для начала, прежде чем минусить.

Comment: @NickEloye Ахах, действительно проглядел. Забавно, как рядом стоящие слова прогуливать и гугл объединились в мозгу:) А вы не злитесь, добрее надо быть. К тому же я ни минусил ни вопрос, ни один из ответов.

Comment: @МаксимФисман, терпимость погубит нас всех . Парень не сделал ни чего, что бы заслужить ответа.